# Android libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, android-studio

Why Am I getting this error in my gradle?
It works fine if I run it,
But I just don't want to get in trouble once I release my application.

[image]

Comment: the only solution i could find was to download all the libraries as a module and edit their dependencies so that whole project uses same version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error itself says everything `Android libraries must use the exact same version`

Use the same version for each support library, you might have used different versions for different support libraries.

Comment: Had to change my Facebook SDK to lower version to fixed the Error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

compileSdkVersion and support libraries version should be same. otherwise that could be the cause of runtime crash. but it'll still compile your project